# I am stuck in the middle of the project and facing errors in .net core in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have made 3 table in the database which shows me error in this program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As per error, there is no "BuildTargetModel" to override. Any reason you are using override. If you are overriding, it has to be in base class

Comment: You're mixing up entity classes and the DbContext.